# SQL Indicate Completion once 2 matching result queries are matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 queries. I basically need to work out from the 2 queries when the all threads have completed processing and alert in a form of Print Complete. To do this - If the current Processing query matches total put through query output number, All threads are completed in that batch. I need to create a stored proc that would PRINT Complete. What would be the best way of doing this?

--How Many To Process - Which is put through first (but not processed)

```
  SELECT COUNT(IsProcessed) as 'Current Put through' 
  FROM [dbo].[threads]
```

-- Current Processed -- This incrementally goes up by the Isprocessed flag   changing 1 by 1 to the value of 1

```
SELECT COUNT(IsProcessed) 'Current_Processing' 
FROM [dbo].[threads] as count
where IsProcessed=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like the following?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Threads WHERE IsProcessed != 1) 
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Complete'
  END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    PRINT 'Ongoing'
  END
```

Comment: Thanks, but no that did not work. Currently as a test there is 11 processed from an amount of 112, and the statement you provided is printing complete

Comment: Whoops ... I had it backwards.  Try the revised code instead.

Comment: Thank you AHiggins, are we able to put an ELSE in there? I have put an Else in below put syntax error. ELSE to Print 'Still going'

Comment: Pretty simple change, yes - check the new revision

Comment: Boom! That worked Great. Thanks for your help on that

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, 
case when cntAll = cntProcessed then 'Complete' else 'Ongoing' end as Status 
from (
select count(case when IsProcessed = 1 then 1 else NULL end) Current_Processing, 
count(1) 'Current Put through' 
from [dbo].[threads])A
```